# The inverse of $4$ modulo $9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Can someone explain  why the inverse $4$ modulo $9$ is $7$? What am I missing?
$$9 = 2\cdot4 + 1$$
$$1 = 9-4\cdot2$$
$$1 = -2\cdot4 + 1\cdot9$$

Isn't then $-2$ inverse of $4$ modulo $9$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct, but remember that $-2 \equiv 7 \pmod 9$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the modular multiplicative inverse x of 4(mod 9), we must solve the equation

x = 4^(-1)(mod 9)

4x = 1(mod 9)

4x = 28(mod 9)

x = 7(mod 9)

The multiplicative inverse is 7. If you multiply a number by its inverse, you get 1.

7*4 = 28, but 28(mod 9) = 1.

Comment: You kind of missed the point, John! See Johanna's answer.